# How to make the UI similar to the attached image. .

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want to make the following UI [image]

I have tried and the similar UI is visible in XML, but when I populate it in my device. The apple image comes inside the dialog box (which should be half above and half below it). Here is my XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/name_iv"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity=""
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user_icon" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/et_fullName"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="8"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="Full Name"
                        android:textColorHint="#333"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:background="#333" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textFormSize"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />



            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bannerimage"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I have done this :

```
 tv_pay_now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(OrderSummaryActivity.this);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.otp_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("OTP Verification");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Please tell me how make this UI? Thanks

Comment: set background color transparent

Comment: @DivyeshPatel background color of Parent LinearLayout ? 
I have already done that it's not working. 
any other suggestion ?

Comment: set top linear and framelayout background color Transparent and , when you create dialog add this line before dialog.show();     dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, Thanks!! It worked. the white background color was the main issue.

Comment: @rajat44 did your issue solved.

Comment: @jagapathi yes!!

Answer (score 0):

> First in your Activity add
>   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); for dialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.otp_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
```

And this is sample XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OUTPUT IMAGE

[image]